# using Bootstrap webpage it should be responsive in mobile,tablet and desktop

Tags: bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF8Lt.jpg)

how to create code for it
using Bootstrap webpage it should be responsive in mobile,tablet and desktop

Comment: You need a tutorial on how to use bootstrap as a beginner

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.